# Unit of measurement for ECG data

Tags: movesense

I'm working on ECG data I'm getting from a Movesense 2.0.0 HR+ sensor by using `/meas/ECG` API.
I'd like to know what's the unit of measurement for them and if they can be converted to milliVolts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct scaling factor is:

```
VOLTS_PER_LSB = 1.0f / 20.0f / (1 << 17);
```

i.e. one LSB corresponds to 0.38147 uV

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*